# BTC sent to my ether wallet for swap into ETH, but its not showing BTC or even ETH

Tags: go-ethereum, myetherwallet, transaction-propagation

I have sent some BTC into myetherwallet account from unocoin,from unocoin it took time of 48 hours in transferring the BTC to myetherwallet (due to some technical issue). And now, BTC is transferred from my unocoin account to myetherwallet account, but its not showing my BTC or respective value ETH. Please help me out in getting my BTC/ETH which I have lost(without any reason). Dropped mail to myetherwallet support team, even they are also not responding. Please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid I don't quite follow your question. It is not possible to transfer Bitcoin to an Ethereum wallet or vice versa. The two crypto-currencies operate on completely different blockchains and have different addressing schemes.

I have to assume that you meant that you had BTC in unocoin, sold it for ETH and transferred that to your ethereum wallet that you created using MyEtherWallet.

I recommend contacting unocoin and get the Tx id of the transaction they made to your Ethereum address. That will allow you to see if the transaction has been confirmed by the network and verify that it indeed was sent to the correct account.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Akstat ! Yes, you are right and I check with Tx id, transaction successfully done & I'm having Hash id & also able to trace the transaction, but unable to find any solution to get back my BTC or ETH.

Comment: So you have a Tx id. Can you post that here so we can look at it? The ultimate question will be whether or not you control the private key to the account that you transferred your ETH to.